# как на белом фоне с прозрачностью вывести белый текст

Tags: css

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #190059;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто дать тень:  `text-shadow`

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, nobis, nostrum! Odio sint facilis libero magni soluta maiores illum dicta!
```

не по теме, но есть плюшки которые поддерживаются в 80% браузерах

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
max-width:100%;
}

.hero {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/459370/Wallace_Home_01%20Copy%2025.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero__title {
  position: relative;
}

.hero__title:before,
.hero__title:after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:3em;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.hero__title-text {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  color: white;
  font-size:3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='hero'>
  <h1 class='hero__title' data-text="The Orient">
    <span class='hero__title-text'>The orient</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, нужно вывести белым шрифтом текст на белом фоне, у фона стоит opacity: 0.7 и чтобы шрифт оставался ярко белым, а не становился серым, под цвет подложки

Answer (score 1):

Все просто: подобрать цвет подложки вместо прозрачности и подложка останется прозрачной и цвета элементов на подложке сохранят свою яркость

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
background-color: #190059;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: relative;
}

div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1){
 background-color: #f9f3f38f;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Все получится</p>
  </div>
</div>
```